# how can I add Js code fro Dropbox chooser to angular

Tags: javascript, angular, dropbox

Hello I am working on adding Dropbox chooser to my website and as far as I know there is no angular version for the code provided, I know nothing about JS I tried to do it my self, but I failed .
based on this [exemple](https://codepen.io/kjohnson/pen/qnlkz) I added the JS code to index.html like this

```
<script src="dropbox-picker.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/2/dropins.js" id="dropboxjs" data-app-key="oe0zfohwirh12e5"></script>
<div >
  


<div class="row">
  <div class="small-12 columns">
    
    <div id="dropbox-container" #ff></div>
    <hr>
    <ul id="img_list" >

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
   </div>
<script>
  /**
 * Chooser (Drop Box)
 * https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/chooser/js
 */
options = {
    success: function(files) {
      files.forEach(function(file) {
        add_img_to_list(file);
      });
    },
    cancel: function() {
      //optional
    },
    linkType: "preview", // "preview" or "direct"
    multiselect: true, // true or false
    extensions: ['.png', '.jpg'],
};

var button = Dropbox.createChooseButton(options);
document.getElementById("dropbox-container").appendChild(button);

function add_img_to_list(file) {
  var li  = document.createElement('li');
  var a   = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = file.link;
  var img = new Image();
  var src = file.thumbnailLink;
  src = src.replace("bounding_box=75", "bounding_box=256");
  src = src.replace("mode=fit", "mode=crop");
  img.src = src;
  img.className = "th"
  document.getElementById("img_list").appendChild(li).appendChild(a).appendChild(img);
}
</script>
```

and it worked I got the Dropbox button, so I tried to move it to app.component.html, and it despaired I tried to add the JS code in a different file and add it to script in angular.js but I failed it did not work
so what should do

Comment: Any solutions...?

Comment: Any Solutions.....?